# 'Nchoosek' or Excel query

Tags: excel, octave, vba

Data is in the following format, with each row one data set:

```
     Column A          Column B
      Abc              123
      Def              456
      Ghi              789
      Jkl              000
```

I am trying to list combinations of all possible groups of three data sets. For example:

```
      Column A.  B.   C.    D.   E.  F.
      Abc       123  Def    456  Ghi 789
      Abc       123  Def    456  Jkl 000
      Def       456  Ghi    789  Jkl 000
      Abc.      123 Ghi     789  JKl 000
```

In reality the actual number of columns exceeds 150 and rows exceed 50, so [Excel permutations without repetition from values in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689075/excel-permutations-without-repetition-from-values-in-multiple-columns) is not applicable.

Comment: What have you coded thus far? Please show is the current state of you code.

Comment: Why not `Abc 123 Ghi 789 Jkl 000`?

Comment: The 4th possibility has been added in for clarity as pointed out by Axel. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could have the approach from your link a little bit more general. My code should be able working with a variable count of columns.

```
Sub CreatePermutation()

 Dim lFirstCellRow As Long
 Dim lSecondCellRow As Long
 Dim lThirdCellRow As Long
 Dim lNumRows As Long
 Dim iNumCols As Integer
 Dim lOutputRow As Long

 With ActiveSheet

  'start your source data in A1 without empty cells
  lNumRows = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row()
  If lNumRows = .Rows.Count Then lNumRows = 1
  iNumCols = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column()
  If iNumCols = .Columns.Count Then iNumCols = 1

  'target data will begin after one empty row below the source data
  lOutputRow = lNumRows + 2

  For lFirstCellRow = 1 To lNumRows - 2
   For lSecondCellRow = lFirstCellRow + 1 To lNumRows - 1
    For lThirdCellRow = lSecondCellRow + 1 To lNumRows

     .Range(.Cells(lOutputRow, 1), .Cells(lOutputRow, iNumCols)).Value = .Range(.Cells(lFirstCellRow, 1), .Cells(lFirstCellRow, iNumCols)).Value
     .Range(.Cells(lOutputRow, 1 + iNumCols), .Cells(lOutputRow, 2 * iNumCols)).Value = .Range(.Cells(lSecondCellRow, 1), .Cells(lSecondCellRow, iNumCols)).Value
     .Range(.Cells(lOutputRow, 1 + 2 * iNumCols), .Cells(lOutputRow, 3 * iNumCols)).Value = .Range(.Cells(lThirdCellRow, 1), .Cells(lThirdCellRow, iNumCols)).Value

     lOutputRow = lOutputRow + 1

    Next lThirdCellRow
   Next lSecondCellRow
  Next lFirstCellRow

 End With

End Sub
```